# Hexadecimal notation for a MIPS program

Tags: mips, hex

What I usually do is code using assembly language and then use an assembler to convert it into binary code to run it.

My homework says:

```
Write the hexadecimal notation for a MIPS machine language program that...
```

Soo do I write the assembly language version of the program and then turn it into hex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is to:

- Write your program in MIPS assembly
- Either assembly by hand or using a MIPS assembler
- Then *look* the machine code generated and write it in hex format (if you have a binary representation of each machine instruction issued by your assembler just group them in 4 bits chunks and convert each chunck to the hexadecimal value, i.e. 0000=0, 0001=1, ..., 1010=A, 1011=B, ..., 1111=F)